# App not running properly on iPhone 6 simulator

Tags: ios

I am stuck with this weird problem. When I put Launch Screen File (Under General Settings tab) as empty, app runs well on 4s, 5, 6. 
But when I put some Launch Screen for app, it gets scaled on iPhone6. Any help on this would be appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check your splash screen size
splash screen must be

```
2x            640 × 960 pixels
ratina        640 × 1136 pixels
ratina hd 4.7 750 × 1334 pixels
ratina hd 5.5 1242 × 2208 pixels
```

and also use autoresizing mask

Answer (score 0):

set property in your image and view

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you don't add splash screen the UI is automatically scaled up by the IOS to fit the bigger screens. SO your all UI scaled autmatically so it looks fine.

But when you add splash screen it will take the frame and size as it is.

You can solve it by using autolayout and size class.

Answer (score 0):

You getting problem because you may not using Ratina HD 4.7 (750X1334) Launchscreen.

Include launchscreens for every resolution shown in below image, then it will run perfect on all your iPhones.
[image]

Or you can check also full tutorial about Launchscreen
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/

Answer (score 0):

You should not add splash images for the `Retina HD 4.7`, `Retina HD 5.5` in your launch images, when you add these it means your app is compatible with iPhone 6, iPhone 6+ respectively. And by screenshot i can see that you app is still not compatible with iPhone6, iPhone 6+.